# Subdomains in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

as I am trying to create web with subodmain for every user i coded as below:

In below controller i am checking if subdomain from sign_in devise page belons to user in User.rb table. If not i am logging out.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :check_domain

    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:slug])
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:slug])
    end

    def check_domain
      unless current_user.nil?
        @domain = User.find_by(email: current_user.email)
        if @domain.slug != request.subdomain
            sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)
            flash.alert = "User not found."
        end
      end
    end

end
```

At this moment I have routes.rb as below:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :devise
  resources :places
    resources :people_items
    resources :people, only: [:edit, :update]
    resources :gift_items
    resources :gifts, only: [:edit, :update]
    resources :program_items
    resources :story_items
    devise_for :users
    root to: 'pages#index'
    get '/home', to: 'output#home'
    # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

    resources :pages do
     member do
       delete :delete_file
     end
    end

    resources :stories, only: [:edit, :update]
    resources :programs, only: [:edit, :update]
    resources :galleries, only: [:edit, :update] do
     member do
       delete :delete_image
     end
    end

    get 'informations/information'

    resources :aboutus, only: [:edit, :update]

end
```

I modified one more settings in config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 1
```

Everything is working fine.

In tutorials i found out that for working subdomains properly I should modify routes.rb as below. But what is the purpose of modification file below? Do I really need to touch routes.rb? That's my question.

```
 constraints subdomain: /.*/ do
   resources :pages
 end
```

Do I really need to modify this? Or what is purpose of this modification? Is that really necessary?

Thank you so much for your advices!

Comment: I'm unsure of the problem you're struggling with? Do you have an error? Is something not working the way you expect?

Comment: Hi @Jon - i modifed the qeuestion. Basically everything is working. But I do not get the point what is constraint subdomain: in routes.rb good for. Could you please advise?

Comment: It just adds a constraint for any routes within that block. However, the constraint regex of `/.*/` will just allow everything.

Comment: For context, I also use subdomains within one of my applications, and have this in my routes: `constraints ->(req) { Site.exists?(domain: req.host) || Rails.configuration.x.subdomain_hosts.include?(req.domain) && Site.exists?(subdomain: req.subdomain) } do`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints in `routes.rb` allow you to restrict when routes should or shouldn't be matched, returning a 404 in the event that they do not.

You can do this on a per-route basis for params like so:

```
get 'products/:category', to: "products#index", category: /(fruit|electronics|medicine)/, as: :products
```

This would allow requests to `http://yourdomain.com/products/fruit` but not to `http://yourdomain.com/products/vehicles` for example. Accessing any forbidden domains would provide you with a 404 response.

You can provide generic constraints to a bunch of different routes by enclosing them in a constraints block, like so:

```
constraints ->(req) { Site.exists?(subdomain: req.subdomain) } do
  resources :articles, path: "blog", only: [:index, :show]
  ...
end
```

So here, we're checking that a `Site` record exists with the subdomain provided. If not, we return a 404.